# use html 5 or php to manipulate files on server

Tags: php, javascript, html, tomcat, lamp

I need to automate & simplify the way employees send large files to customers.

#### The current use case:

Employee uses scp to send large (2GB+) file to our LAMP server.
Employee ssh into web server
Employee moves file into a new folder inside the web directory
Employee runs chmod on folder
Employee creates .htaccess file with customer name and random password
Employee figures out the public url for the newly created folder & emails customer the link.

I have greatly simplified this procedure via bash scripts, but it still is waaaay too time consuming for the employee. ( over 10 minutes ! ) I need to make a simple html5 webpage the employee can 'drag and drop' the file into and then receive a public link they can send to the customer.

Only internal employees would be able to upload files. Employees and Customers would be able to download the files.

See https://letscrate.com/ for an example of what I am trying to implement.

Unfortunately letscrate.com, dropbox and google drive can not be used to share the large files due to company policies.

Using HTML5 and this example: http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload  I am able to upload the large file to our internal webserver. That is where I am stuck.

#### My question is:

Once I have the large file on the server, how can I move the file to the web directory and setup an .htaccess file?
I'm thinking of running a cron job to periodically move the file to the web root and configure the .htaccess file, but I'd like to do this without running any additional services / cron-tasks on the server.

#### Could this be accomplished though just php, html5, javascript ?

All employees use firefox or chrome (no ie).

Comment: `The current use case` -> crazy! Also it is crazy to let php have access to the `.htaccess` file! damn! Sorry, -1

Comment: put all files in one directory, outside web root, log file name to user, user has login, file served via php

Comment: I don't think browser upload is suitable for 2G+ files. At that site, you're better off having some software on your machine to get it there reliably - say rsync. You don't have to use .htaccess for passwords, you can do it via PHP too.

Answer (score 5):

My first reaction would be this:

- Do an admin where you let the user upload the file (ordinary file upload, flash file upload or HTML5, doesn't matter).
- The file is then stored outside the www-root (no direct access to the file).
- Let the user add a username/password for this file and generate a unique ID/Key for the file.
  (DB columns: id, filename, username, password, url_key).
- Present the full url to the user that they can send to the client.
- When customer loads: mydomain.com/file/the_generated_url_key, you get the key from the url, if it exists, and promt a login box, which you authenticate against the database.

Then you simply do a:

```
echo file_get_contents(path_to_the_real_file);
```

Of course with the correct headers, depending of the file type.

Like the comment said. Do NOT let PHP mess around with the .htaccess, or let the users use SFTP to the server directly.

If you don't want them to upload through a browser, you can't really use HTML5 either, since it's still a browser upload. Let them use FTP (easier to lock what folders they have access to) and let them select the uploaded file from the admin and set username/password and to generate a URL.